# how to layer CCLabel over video

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to place a CCLabelBMFont object over a playing video. How can I achieve this? I am using the MPMoviePlayerController to play the video. Also, can I specify the duration, start time and end time that the label will appear?

Comment: I think you could certainly dress up the MPMoviePlayerController's view with some UIKit classes, as well as animate+time the appearance . . is there any reason why you can't fall back to UIKit for this, since you're already using the UIKit based controller?

Comment: What you can **not** do is: cocos2d background, movie player on top, cocos2d label on top of movie player. The cocos2d (any OpenGL) view and its content are on one layer, the movie player either above or below it. You can certainly add a UILabel or UIBotton on top of the movie player.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: So how do I use a UILabel to display my custom font (.fnt file as is done with CCLabelBMFont) over a movie?